How to avoid class Foo from being treated as __main__.Foo?
I have these two classes Foo and Bar which are separated in two different files (foo.py and bar.py) for organization purposes. They both implement a __add__ method. I want both __add__ methods to work whether other is an instance of class Foo or Bar.
However, if foo is an instance of class Foo and bar is an instance of class Bar, and I attempt to add bar + foo in the module foo, Boo's __add__ method will treat foo as __main__.Foo and will raise TypeError. The code in question can be summerized like so:
from typing import Union, Any

import bar as b

FooBar = Union['Foo', 'b.Bar']


class Foo:
    message: str

    def __init__(self, message: str) -> None:
        self.message = message

    def __add__(self, other: Any) -> 'Foo':
        if not isinstance(other, (Foo, b.Bar)):
            raise TypeError('can only add Foo and Bar')
        return Foo(' '.join((self.message, other.message)))


def test():
    foo = Foo('Jalim')
    bar = b.Bar('Rabei')
    foobar = foo + bar # works just fine
    print(foobar.message)
    barfoo = bar + foo # raises TypeError because it receives __main__.Foo
    print(barfoo.message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()


from typing import Union, Any

import foo as f

FooBar = Union['f.Foo', 'Bar']


class Bar:
    message: str

    def __init__(self, message: str) -> None:
        self.message = message

    def __add__(self, other: Any) -> 'Bar':
        if not isinstance(other, (f.Foo, Bar)):
            print(f'{type(other) = }')
            raise TypeError('can only add Foo and Bar')
        return Bar(''.join((self.message, other.message)))


I know I could run test() in another file, but I'd like to be able to run from foo.py and while circunventing, if possible, the conversion from Foo to __main__.Foo.
At first, I tried using the type alias FooBar instead of a tuple (Foo, bar.Bar). However, since FooBar doens't really hold types and, instead, holds ForwardRefs, it can't be used in isinstance. I can't put Foo and Bar instead of 'Foo' and 'b.Bar' into a Union either, because it would generate a circular dependency issue.

I don't think it's possible for if __name__ == '__main__': to be true and also have the name defined in the foo namespace. The right solution is to put the test function in its own file that imports both foo and bar.

For once, I agree with Barmar.

With this structure, your class Foo is going to be created twice. It will exist with dual identities in two separate modules, and with two different memory locations:
sys.modules["foo"].Foo
sys.modules["__main__"].Foo

For all practical purposes, they are different types, even though they have the same source code.
The foo.Foo is created first, when the line import bar as b was executed, which itself triggers import foo as f. Then __main__.Foo is created, when the class definition is again encountered during the execution of the script in the top-level code environment.
The solution is to separate the test code from the library code.
Library code:
# foo.py
class Foo:
    ...

# bar.py
class Bar:
    ...

Test code:
from foo import Foo
from bar import Bar

def test_stuff():
    ...

With this pattern, your top-level code environment will be a test script (or, more commonly, a test runner's entry-point) and the Foo type will only exist once, in the foo module namespace.

Thanks, wim! Loved the answer. Though, in the case of executing the testing code in another file, could I still import foo in bar and vice-versa in order to check the type of other in __add__?

@RenanElfo Yes, you should be able to. Circular imports are ok, as long as they don't create circular dependency problem, and it doesn't look like this case will.  If you had used from foo import Foo instead of import foo as f, then you may have had a problem.
